# Corax and the Curse

Tags: world-of-darkness, werewolf-the-apocalypse

We have a group of characters (in the oWoD) that stumbled upon a kinfolk played by another player. He now senses the rage of the changing breeds (two garou and a corax), otherwise known as the curse.

Since I'm not finding any mention of the Corax being subjected to the Curse, is there any mention in the rules that humans react the same way to the rage in a corax?
I know that the Corax induce a reduced delirium, so I'd house rule it, that the effect of the rage inside a Corax would have also a reduced effect on the humans.
Or isn't a Kinfolk affected by the Curse?

Comment: The [rules-as-written] tag is only for highly legalistic interpretations/rules exploit discussion, not general rules questions, so I've removed it.

Comment: Kinfolk are also affected by the curse http://whitewolf.wikia.com/wiki/Curse_(WTA)

Answer (score 2):

I believe it states in the books that Corax were not part of the Impergium (being crows) so there is no subconscious human instinct to be terrified of them.

However, to keep the veil they sort of "stuffed" in there that the supernatural rage exuded by a corax in its war form is "reminiscent" of a crinos and therefore causes delirium.

I think they just did that so you didn't have can-can corax dancers in war form waltzing down the street in front of mortals. Since they're very independent and don't have a brutal garou tribe to reign them in it might take a while before they got shut down by other supernatural creatures.

Comment: Tiny addendum: the only tribe that really doesn't cause Delirium is Kitsune - due to not being part of the Impergium and having not existed back then.

Answer (score 0):

## W20: Changing Breeds

W20CB forgets it in the Corax entry, but makes a clear statement on page 217, The Veil’s Effect:

> - Corax: Crinos form incites reduced Delirium.

## Revised: Players Guide to the Changing Breeds

The PGttCB simply forgets to mention if they do any delirium in their direct entry. BUT there is page 157, The Veil's Effects:

> - Corax: Crinos form incites reduced Delirium.

## 2nd Ed: Breed Book 3 - Corax

The Breedbook has it the most open. Traits, Page 62, reads:

> - The Delirium of the Crinos form is lessened, affecting
>   onlookers as if their Willpower were two points higher.

## Kinfolk and the curse

It has been in all the editions, that all Kinfolk simply ignore having to roll for Delirium, no matter what they are related to. A Bastet Kinfolk is immune to the Delirium of a Corax, a Kitsune Kinfolk (usually a useless trait) is immune to a Khan's Delirium etc.